# Testing GLIMMIX assumptions

Tags: anova, count-data, sas

I am currently doing GLIMMIX models in SAS. I choosed GLIMMIX as my data is count data, generally well described by a Poisson distribution.

My question: What assumptions can you test to ensure that your model is appropriate with GLIMMIX ?

From SAS, I learn the assumptions of GLIMMIX (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glimmix_a0000001402.htm) but I'm not sure I understand them. And I don't see how I could test them.

I also know that when the Pearson chi-square/DF is approximately 1, Poisson is good and when it's > 1, you should use a negative binomial.

Is there anything else ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

After verification with people at my lab, I think I can answer my own question:

No, there is nothing else.

I will be very happy if anyone else has a different answer, but I think mine is correct.

Comment: Can you tell me what did you find out about testing the glimmix assumptions?

Comment: @Marcel chi-square/df seems to be the only thing. You could check for outliers, but that's about it! Does it answer your question?